# Discrepancy wolfram alpha and hand calculation of a gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, hypergeometric-function, gaussian-integral, wolfram-alpha

[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D*Power%5Be%2C-a*Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5D%2CSqrt%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bm%2C2%5D%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%2B%5Cinfty%7D%5D) gives me the following result:
$$ \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^2\, e^{-a x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 +m^2}}\, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4 a} U\Big(\frac{1}{2},0, a m^2 \Big)$$
and it does use the [usual definition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)
$$ U(a,b,z) := \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)} \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-zt}\, t^{a-1}\, (1+t)^{b-a-1}\, dt $$
but if one does the calculus by hand, one finds instead (i use brackets to indicate a change of variable)
$$ \begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^2\, e^{-a x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 +m^2}}\, dx &=  \genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{0}{k=\frac{x}{m}}{dk = \frac{1}{m}\, dx} = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{m^2 k^2\, e^{-a m^2 k^2}}{\sqrt{k^2 +1}}\, dx\\
&= \genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{0}{t=k^2}{dt = 2\hspace{.6pt} k\, dk} = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{m^2 t e^{-\hspace{.3pt}2\hspace{.3pt} n\hspace{.3pt} m^2 t}}{\sqrt{t +1}}\, \frac{dt}{2 \sqrt{t}} = \frac{m^2}{2} \Gamma\Big(\frac{3}{2} \Big) U \Big(\frac{3}{2},2,2\hspace{.3pt} n\hspace{.3pt} m^2 \Big)
\end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to answer directly, I understood while writting...

One finds the [Kummer's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer%27s_transformation) relating both expressions... so they really are equal... no bug in the matrix...